# finding array index from view in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, indexing

how can I fetch one particular index from the array to delete? e.g. if I have `array[a, b, c]` in the array list and want to delete `b` which is index `array[1]` from it? Any help would be great.

I need to pass index to the controller so I can delete it

**View**

```
@foreach (json_decode($p->filename) as $picture)
   <ul>
     <a href="/delete-product-image-name/{{$p->id}}?index={{ $loop->index }}">Delete</a>
   </ul>
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
public function deleteProductImageName($id) {
        if(Auth::check()) {

            $products = Product::where('id', $id)->first();

            foreach($products as $p) {
                if(($products->user_id == Auth::user()->id) && ($products->id == $id)) {
                  $product = Product::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                        ->where('id', $id)->first();

                     $filename_index = $product->filename;

                echo $filename_index; '<br/>';
                echo $filename_index . '[' . $index . ']';
                }
            }
        } else {
            Session::flash("message", "OOPS! You dont have permission to delete the items. Please login first.");
            return redirect("/register-user");

        }
    }
```

**UPDATED**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Loop Variables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable).

**To get the current index, you can use:**

```
$name = $request->query('name');
```

### EDIT

Ok I understand the question better. You want to add additional parameters to the request.

**View Example**

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <a href="/delete/{{$item->id}}?index={{ $loop->index }}">Delete</a>
@endforeach
```

**Controller Example**

```
public function delete($id) {
   // get the query parameter
   $index = $request->query('index');
}
```

Comment: how to pass this in my case ? This is getting bit of a tough for me

Comment: I added an example using query parameters

Comment: this is working. I am getting the index number through `$filename_index = $product->filename[$index];` but when I try to delete it through `dd($filename_index->delete());` , it gives me an error `Call to a member function delete() on string`

Comment: Can you update your code in your question so we can see more context?

Comment: I have updated the code. I am trying all possible ways but failing

Comment: There is no new code after you updated, I do not see where you are calling the $filename_index->delete() in your code. Either way that $filename_index is not an object that has the delete() method available. It is a string. You will need to take that index, and look up some other object from eloquent, or if you are simply trying to remove that index form the array, you can use [unset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)